# {OpenGL 3.3+} GL_BLEND doesn't work

Tags: transparency, blending

Yesterday i start to writting my 2D Engine in C++ + GLFW + OpenGL 3.3 + GL3W + DevIL.
But i have really big problem :/ glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); doesn't work :/ i've tried everything! ;/ 
My glTexImage2D :

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width,height, 0, GL_RGBA, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ilGetData());
```

My texture ( normally it have alpha ;p ) : 
[Texture Link](https://lhswug.sn2.livefilestore.com/y1pngL2hUxdwtHTW-yfB7NJxmLHw1QlNq8uptMJwWSpf18FA332jJ8GOzXIkpLpwmjbp5Qo1BoCLGrlGX0BzOGU5c3kEAt1340R/Player.png?psid=1)

Result with glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); : 
[glBlend Result Link](https://public.sn2.livefilestore.com/y1pBc7Ajmb-pLrZEUEcLb6JBhvK1W9CYu0p3afYpbs6UbswNocemkTrPA4H5oJrs6t7FaKlB0EjX9hFU_w0kjtC7Q/result1.png?psid=1)

Please help me.

Thanks for help!